# How to have List<String> property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How do I have a List property in a Realm object? I want to save the strings to the same object not to have 
related objects each having a single string (which I assume happens if I use some StringWrapper class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use List for that.

> [List](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html) for to-many relationships

However you can achieve what you want by combining all your strings into one, separated by a character. You use this

> func componentsSeparatedByString(_ separator: String) -> [AnyObject]

afterwards to get your Array back from it.

Comment: Realm should do that internally. Why do I have to do the serialization myself?

Comment: That's how databases work. If you have an array of objects then you save them to database and make the relations. If you want them all in a property then you serialize yourself.

Comment: That's how it is in relational databases, but not in object or nosql databases.

Comment: Btw. is there any difference in using List or Array for relations?

Comment: I think you can only use List for relations. It's the object that they implemented for working with to many relations. It works pretty much like an array but I suppose they thought it's better to have a different name not to cause confusion.